# MySQL select in join clause scanning too many rows

Tags: mysql, performance, join

Oke guys, the following has been bugging me all day:

I use the query below to select an overview of products and prices including the latest result-price based on field StartTime from another table (tresults). To do this I thought I would need a subselect in the join.

The problem is that the EXPLAIN function is telling me that MySQL is scanning ALL result rows (225000 rows) not using any index.

Is there some way I can speed this up? Preferably by adding a WHERE statement to have mysql look only at the rows with the corresponding pID's.

```
select p.pID, brandname, description, p.EAN, RetailPrice, LowestPrice, min(price), min(price)/lowestprice-1 as afwijking
from tproducts p
    join ( 
    select Max(tresults.StartTime) AS maxstarttime, tresults.pID
    from tresults
    -- maybe adding a where clause here?
    group by tresults.pID
    ) p_max on (p_max.pID = p.pID)
join tresults res on (res.starttime = p_max.maxstarttime and p.pID = res.pID and res.websiteID = 1)
join tsupplierproducts sp on (sp.pID = p.pID AND supplierID = 1)
join tbrands b on (b.brandID = p.BrandID)
group by p.pID, brandname, description, p.EAN, RetailPrice, LowestPrice
```

Indexes are on all columns that are part of joins or where clauses.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add some information about what indexes are set on your tables? Is there an index set on the tresults.StartTime column for instance?

Comment: I've added an extra line. Pretty much everything that is in joins or where clauses is indexed. The root of the problem is in the join (select...) part

Answer (score 0):

From your SQL I assume that you are listing product based on 1 supplier (supplierID = 1) only.

Best practice is do your **known filter at begin of sql** to eliminate record, then use inner join to join other without filter table.

```
select p.pID, brandname, description, p.EAN, RetailPrice, LowestPrice, min(price), min(price)/lowestprice-1 as afwijking
from 
(select p.pID, p.BrandID p.EAN, Max(t.StartTime) AS maxstarttime
FROM tproducts p INNER JOIN tresults t on supplierID=1 and p.pID=t.pID
group by tresults.pID
) p 
inner join tresults res on (res.websiteID = 1 and p.pID = res.pID and res.starttime = p_max.maxstarttime)
inner join tsupplierproducts sp on (sp.pID = p.pID)
inner join tbrands b on (b.brandID = p.BrandID)
group by p.pID, brandname, description, p.EAN, RetailPrice, LowestPrice
```

from above code, I eliminate all supplierID != 1 from tproducts before join tresults.

let me know if the above sql help, and what is the EXPLAIN function result

:-)

Comment: Thanks. I eliminated all all products that are not supplierID=1. I did it in a slightly different way since supplierID is not in the results table and not in the products table. The speed was a little better, but not a lot. Most probably due to the fact that almost all products are from supplierID=1.

Comment: Adding this to the where clause helped a lot: tresults.StartTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW(). I did this because the maxdate is likely to be within the past 7 days. But there has to be a better way... I think